# Nested stmt mysqli PHP

Tags: php, mysqli, while-loop

I'm trying to create a third table taking two indexes from two different tables for creating a correlation between them using following code:

```
$query1 = "select iduniverse from universe";
$query2 = "select idfiles from files";
$query3 = "select iduniFiles from uniFiles where filesId = ? and universeId = ?";
$query4 = "insert into uniFiles (filesId, universeId) values (?,?)";

if($stmt1 = $conn->prepare($query1)){
if($stmt2 = $conn->prepare($query2)){
    if($stmt3 = $conn->prepare($query3)){
        if($stmt4 = $conn->prepare($query4)){
            $stmt1->execute();
            $stmt1->bind_result($iduniverse);
            while($stmt1->fetch()){
                $stmt2->execute();
                $stmt2->bind_result($idfiles);
                while($stmt2->fetch()){
                    $stmt3->bind_param("ii", $idfiles, $iduniverse);
                    $stmt3->execute();
                    $stmt3->store_result();
                    if($stmt3->num_rows == 0){
                        $stmt4->bind_param("ii", $idfiles, $iduniverse);
                        $stmt4->execute();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        $stmt4->free_result();
    }
    $stmt3->free_result();
 }
 $stmt2->free_result();
}
$stmt1->free_result();
```

But if I put an echo "here\n" after second while loop:

```
while($stmt2->fetch()){
  echo "here\n";
  ...
```

When I launch my code I don't see anything on screen output and also table uniFiles remains empty.

I have already checked query via SQL Browser and works without any issue. So I don't understand where is the mistake.

What is wrong in my script?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A mysqli connection can only hold a single active prepared statement at a time.

Therefore, you can't have nested prepared statements active on the same connection.  You'll have to have a separate connection for each level of the nesting if you need to keep them all active (at least for each one you don't want squashed by the next level's query.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a join table using [`INSERT INTO INTO SELECT ...`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html)

```
insert into uniFiles (filesId, universeId)
select iu.iduniverse, if.idfiles 
from universe iu
join files if on if.idfiles = iu.idfiles
```

If there could be duplicates, then combine with `INSERT IGNORE`

```
insert ignore into uniFiles (filesId, universeId)
select iu.iduniverse, if.idfiles 
from universe iu
join files if on if.idfiles = iu.idfiles
```